# Good shower gel and shampoo for children to use

Tags: cleaning, bathing

I've had a look not just on here, but Google too, and there's nothing in particular recommending any shower gel or shampoo for younger children. Can most children just use adult shower products? Or should they be using something different?

Our daughter is 5 years old, nearly 6, and we're now transitioning her from the bath to the shower. She's doing fine with it, but she's using Johnson's bedtime baby bath and baby shampoo, and we think it might be time for something a bit stronger. There doesn't seem to be anything for children past being babies, and we don't want to irritate her skin.

Does anyone have any good recommendations? Even if it's just 'use adult products' that would be helpful.

Comment: Can't speak to what you _should do_, so not an answer, but we have never used baby shampoo.  We're very careful to not get it in the eyes, but it's nothing that a quick flush with water won't fix.  That said, since she's never had "the real thing" she might not be very good about keeping it out of her eyes, so make sure she knows that very well at the transition.

Answer (score 1):

Does the current soap not get her clean?

Our kids use California Baby shampoo & bodywash with lavender, and they have used them since they were babies - the oldest is now 5. I will keep using it as long as they like it, as I personally prefer to use products without parabens on my kids.

I find the shampoo fine, and can use it on myself too if needed.

For hand washing, we use regular liquid hand soap.

That said, I don't think there is anything inherently wrong using 'adult' products on kids (and even babies), if you feel the ingredient list is acceptable to you.

While not always unbiased, I find [EWG's Skin Deep](http://www.ewg.org/skindeep/) database useful in finding products for my family.

Answer (score 0):

Some (baby-)soap to wash their hands and bottom with should be all you need.  Use as little as possible and only water most of the time.